# How to implement a Swagger API spec for a ballerina API?

Tags: ballerina

I have a simple API written using Ballerina and would like to create a swagger doc which would be accessible by other developers to get an idea of the API. How can I do this in ballerina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bal openapi` is the tool that will generate an OpenAPI file

`bal openapi -i hello_service.bal --service /hello`
Check out the documentation here. https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/openapi/1.8.0
This command would generate an OpenAPI specification yaml file. And in the could you can see a visualization  section which can be used to get the visual representation of this.